# Combinatorial Proof Of Binomial Double Counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ and $n$ be non-negative integers.

By counting the number of committees 
consisting of $n$ sentient beings that can
be chosen from a pool of $a$ kittens, $b$
crocodiles and $c$ emus in two different
ways, prove the identity

$$\sum\limits_{\substack{i,j,k \ge 0; \\ i+j+k = n}} {{a \choose i}\cdot{b \choose j}\cdot{c \choose k} = {a+b+c \choose n}}$$

where the sum is over all non-negative integers $i$, $j$ and $k$ such that $i+j+k=n.$

I know that this is some kind of combinatorial proof. My biggest problem is that I've never really done a proof.

Answer (score 5):

On the righthand side, we form a committee of size $n$ by lumping all the animals together (so there are $a + b + c$ animals total) and choosing $n$ of them.

On the lefthand side, we form a committee of size $n$ by first choosing exactly $i$ kittens, $j$ crocodiles, and $k$ emus (subject to $i + j + k = n$). For fixed $i$, $j$, and $k$, there are 
$$
\binom{a}{i}\binom{b}{j}\binom{c}{k}
$$
such committees. Summing over all possible partitions of the integer $n$ means we've formed the committees in every possible way, which is precisely what is counted on the righthand side.

Comment: Logically that makes sense but is there some way of proving this with more than just because it makes sense.

Comment: @barrowspizza What we need to be concerned with is that every committee gets counted *exactly once* by the lefthand side. Every committee is counted at least once because it will appear in the sum at whichever $i$, $j$, $k$ partition corresponds to it. A committee cannot be counted twice because there is only one such partition that corresponds to it. So, every committee is counted exactly once.

Comment: Can what you say be considered a proof though? I just really don't know what constitutes a proof.

Comment: @barrowspizza It could be written more clearly, but it has enough detail *for me*. Whether it has enough detail *for you* or *for your professor* (if it is homework) my be completely different standards.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we want to choose from $a+b$ first before choosing  from $c$ such that $n_a+n_b=r$ then the number of ways of choosing is ($p$ from $a$ and $r-p$ from $b$) $$\sum_{p=0}^r \binom ap\displaystyle\binom b{r-p}$$

Afterward $c$ can must fill $n-(n_a+n_b)=n-r$ spaces so we choose $n-r$ from $c$ and $r$ from $a+b$ which implies that one can rewrite the sum as $$\sum\limits_{\substack{i,j,k \ge 0;\\ i+j+k = n}} {a \choose i}\cdot{b \choose j}\cdot{c \choose k} = \sum_{r=0}^n \binom c{n-r}\left( \sum_{p=0}^r \binom ap\binom b{r-p}\right)=\underbrace{\sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{p=0}^r \binom c{n-r} \binom ap\binom b{r-p}}$$
Note that if $r>n$ then $\displaystyle \binom nr =0$, so the above expression is valid.

Product of three polynomials $$\begin{array}{ll}\sum^a_{i=0}a_ix^i\cdot \sum^b_{j=0}b_jx^j\cdot\sum^c_{k=0}c_kx^k &= \sum^{a+b}_{m=0}\left( \sum_{p=0}^m a_pb_{m-p}\right)x^m \cdot\sum^c_{k=0}c_kx^k \quad\text {we use }d_m=\sum_{p=0}^m a_pb_{m-p}\\&=\sum^{a+b}_{m=0}d_mx^m \cdot\sum^c_{k=0}c_kx^k \\&= \sum^{a+b+c}_{n=0}\left( \sum_{r=0}^n d_rc_{n-r}\right)x^n =\sum^{a+b+c}_{n=0}\left( \sum_{r=0}^n c_{n-r}\left(\sum_{p=0}^r a_pb_{r-p}\right)\right)x^n\\&=\sum^{a+b+c}_{n=0} \sum_{r=0}^n  \sum_{p=0}^ra_p b_{r-p}c_{n-r}\cdot x^n \quad \quad \quad (1) \end{array}$$

By the binomial theorem $(1+x)^{a+b+c}$ $$ \begin{array}{ll}= \sum^{a+b+c}_{n=0}\binom {a+b+c}{n}x^n\\ = (1-x)^a(1-x)^b(1-x)^c\\=\left(\sum^a_{i=0}\binom ai x^i \right)\left(\sum^b_{j=0}\binom bj x^j \right)\left(\sum^c_{k=0}\binom ck x^k \right) \\=\sum^{a+b+c}_{n=0} \underbrace{\sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{p=0}^r \binom c{n-r} \binom ap\binom b{r-p}} x^n  \quad \text{after using result (1)} \end{array}$$

Observe that the under-braced expression is exactly the one under-braced above and it is the coefficient of of $x^n$,  we can then equate it to the coefficient binomial expansion i;e;

$$\binom {a+b+c}{n}=\sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{p=0}^r \binom c{n-r} \binom ap\binom b{r-p}$$

This is the [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) for three polynomials and it is the only *combinatorial* proof I know of.  Thanks to [Douglas S. Stones](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/139/douglas-s-stones) who pointed this out to me in a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221139/seeking-a-proof-of-sum-limits-0-le-i-le-k-binomni-binommk-i-bi#comment496357_221139) I asked.

One can do the same for $4$, $5$, ... but it is exhausting so proof by induction or the one given by Austin is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{i\ +\ j\ +\ k\ =\ n \atop{\vphantom{\LARGE A}i,\ j,\ k\  \geq\ 0}}
{a \choose i}{b \choose j}{c \choose k} = {a + b + c \choose n}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \sum_{i\ +\ j\ +\ k\ =\ n \atop{\vphantom{\LARGE A}i,\ j,\ k\  \geq\ 0}}
> {a \choose i}{b \choose j}{c \choose k}}
> =\sum_{\ell_{a},\ \ell_{b},\ \ell_{c}\  \geq\ 0}{a \choose \ell_{a}}
> {b \choose \ell_{b}}{c \choose \ell_{c}}
> \delta_{\ell_{a}\ +\ \ell_{b}\ +\ \ell_{c},\ n}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{\ell_{a},\ \ell_{b},\ \ell_{c}\  \geq\ 0}{a \choose \ell_{a}}
> {b \choose \ell_{b}}{c \choose \ell_{c}}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
> {1 \over z^{-\ell_{a}\ -\ \ell_{b}\ -\ \ell_{c}\ +\ n\ +\ 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{n\ +\ 1}}
> \bracks{\sum_{\ell_{a}\ \geq\ 0}{a \choose \ell_{a}}z^{\ell_{a}}}
> \bracks{\sum_{\ell_{b}\ \geq\ 0}{b \choose \ell_{b}}z^{\ell_{b}}}
> \bracks{\sum_{\ell_{a}\ \geq\ 0}{c \choose \ell_{c}}z^{\ell_{c}}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{n\ +\ 1}}
> \pars{1 + z}^{a}\pars{1 + z}^{b}\pars{1 + z}^{c}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{a + b + c} \over z^{n\ +\ 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{a + b + c \choose n}}
> \end{align}